# Restful service on open liberty to handle only one request at a time

Tags: java, open-liberty

can open liberty be configured to host a rest service that handles only one request at a time.

I can do it with queues, but I'm trying to avoid request/response architecture to make the API synchronous. Any other ideas would be helpful too.

Comment: Why?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have an API which can listen to a queue or rest calls. This API internally calls another process that is not thread safe

Comment: How about protecting the unsafe code with a lock or `synchronous` block?

Comment: +1 for Steves answer. However if you really just want one request per time you could look at the singleton pattern. And, depending on the possibility to modify the code of the process you call, you could investigate whether that process can be made threadsafe.

Comment: I implemented this with locks